# Laravel routes not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have this code in `api.php` routes file for `laravel 5.4`

```
Route::get('/lectures/{id}', function ()
{
    dd("lecture route");
});

Route::get('/lectures/send-request', function ()
{
    dd("send-request route");
});
```

the problem is that when I visit `localhost:8000/api/lectures/send-request` the output is **'lecture route'** which is for this url `localhost:8000/api/lectures/{id}`

but when I change the orders of routes it will work properly

```
Route::get('/lectures/send-request', function ()
{
    dd("send-request route");
});

Route::get('/lectures/{id}', function ()
{
    dd("lecture route");
});
```

now when I visit `localhost:8000/api/lectures/send-request` the output is **'send-request route'**

**so** what is wrong ? why this is happening ?

Comment: Is your file name api.php? You are not writting this in route.php?

Comment: The {id} is variable so {id} = send-request. The routes file will match the first one it will find. So it all makes sense.

Comment: @Exprator you must did not use laravel 5.4

Comment: @Daan 
Yesss , you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Laravel matches routes top-down. This means that the first route to match is the one being used. `/lectures/send-request` matches `'/lectures/{id}'` and sets `$id` to `'send-request'`.

Comment: yes you're , i just thought that `{id}` represent numeric value

Comment: Laravel interprets all parameters from routes as strings

Answer (score 3):

The routes are working exactly as intended. The routes take precedence the same way they're defined.

```
GET /lectures/{id}
GET /lectures/send-request
```

You've defined two routes where the second route is basically one of options of the first route. When you access `/lectures/send-request` it satisfies the condition for the route `/lectures/{id}` with `id` set to `send-request`.

You can switch the order of routes based on your preference, or you could change one of the route.

Comment: yes you're , i just thought that `{id}` represent numeric value